# Line break power automate

Tags: power-automate

I am trying generate a csv file in Power automate from a sharepoint list, but one of fields I am trying to bring is text, and when generates csv, the text is coming broken…
How can I fix this?

In file content from create file I am using commas to separate fields because I will export csv to internal system

Comment: Show us something like a screenshot.

Comment: You need to enclose in double quotes. `"this is a value\nwith a line break"`